# Error when trying to use linear model function lm()

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression

I am trying to find a linear regression for a built-in jupyterhub dataset. I am currently getting a traceback error stating an `invalid 'envir' argument`. I am not exactly sure what this means so if someone can explain I would really appreciate it.

```
data(faithful)
head(faithful)
```

This is what my dataset looks like.

```
eruptions   waiting
3.600   79
1.800   54
3.333   74
2.283   62
4.533   85
2.883   55
```

This is the code resulting in a traceback error:

```
faithful <- data(faithful)
my_line <- lm(formula = waiting ~ eruptions, data = faithful)
```

When ran this is my error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env): invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
Traceback:

1. lm(formula = waiting ~ eruptions, data = faithful)
2. eval(mf, parent.frame())
3. eval(mf, parent.frame())
4. stats::model.frame(formula = waiting ~ eruptions, data = faithful, 
 .     drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
5. model.frame.default(formula = waiting ~ eruptions, data = faithful, 
 .     drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
6. eval(predvars, data, env)
```

Comment: Remove the comma after data=faithful

Comment: I accidentally added that before, still doesn't work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error on version R v4.0.4

Comment: As a courtesy to other people who want to answer, can you edit your question so it contains the exact function call and output without the extra comma?

Comment: The line `faithful <- data(faithful)` is not necessary. `data()` returne the name of the data set you loaded. It does not return the data itself. When you call `data(faithful)`, the variable `faithful` will just be added to your workspace. Don't try to reassign to that value. Use `rm(faithful)` to remove your incorrect copy.

Comment: The problem is `faithful <- data(faithful)`. Get rid of that line and you are fine. Just check `str(faithful)` before that line and again after. The `data()` function loads a data set into the environment and returns its name, NOT the data.